# How to catch the error page in a website which throw System Error /Server Error In Selenium Webdriver c# and fail in my test case Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to find ways to catch this error in my selenium webdriver c#.Is any method which will catch this error in my test case ? There is system error or Server Error but I am unable to retrieve my error and fail my test cases. All my test cases which have these error (System/Server) end with the result = "Test Passed" instead of showing of the Error.

[Eg: Click to View ServerError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qrgW.png)

[Eg: Click to View System Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxDrL.png)

```
[Test]

    public void TestYamaha()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.161.0.1/iels-admin-dev/Login/Login.aspx");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtUserID")).Click();

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtUserID")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtUserID")).SendKeys("manteng");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtPassword")).SendKeys("Nic15742368");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_cmdLogin")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.161.0.1/iels-admin-dev/Announcement_News/Announcement_News_Search.aspx");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-datepicker-trigger:nth-child(2)")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("1")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_cmdSubmit")).Click();
             Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".clsDataGridAltData a:nth-child(2) > img")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_cmdSubmit")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

This code shows System Error (As shown in the picture) but how I show in my test case.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch block to handle any exception and if required then you can log it in catch block. You should use any assertion library for making it pass/fail.

Note: Don't write everything into Test class.

Comment: i thought of try-catch before , but how will the test case fail when my test script run into a page with system error or server error. It always run as Pass, eventhough error page shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of if the URL contain "Error", it will screenshot and fail the test case    .

```
if (url.Contains("error") || url.Contains("Error") == true)
            {
                Base.ErrorMessage(driver, element);  // screenshot the page 
                throw new SystemException("Webpage throw error");
                //Console.WriteLine("Got");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passed");
            }

            }
```